# LinqtoSQL нет шаблона в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, linq2sql, websqldatabase, visual-studio-2017

Через поиск в самой *Visual Studio* не нашел шаблона.
Необходима ли для этого шаблона *Enterprise* версия?
Есть ли возможность его заменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон есть, просто он не устанавливается в стандартном наборе компонент. Для того, чтобы его задействовать, Вам необходимо запустить инсталлятор среды разработки и выбрать необходимый компонент. Компонент доступен для установки во всех версиях `Visual Studio 2017` (`Community`, `Professional`, `Enterprise`). Запускаем инсталлятор и кликаем кнопку <kbd>Изменить</kbd>, в уже установленной среде разработки:

[image: Инсталлятор]

Далее переходим на вкладку <kbd>Отдельные компоненты</kbd>.

[image: Выбор дополнительных компонент]

Переходим к группе <kbd>Средства для работы с кодом</kbd>, там находим пункт <kbd>Инструменты LINQ to SQL</kbd>, ставим галочку, нажимаем кнопку <kbd>Изменить</kbd>, в правом нижнем углу, ждем загрузки и установки компонент, перегружаем компьютер и пользуемся. Чтобы внести изменения - среда разработки должна быть закрыта (о чем говорит надпись на втором изображении).